# Assistive Touch Button in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Can we have an Assistive Touch Button within our Xamarin Forms Application? Any one can suggest some reference or code please. Thank You

Comment: To use an assistive touch button in Xamarin.Forms app, you could try the [SfRadialMenu](https://nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfRadialMenu) plugin. The 'SfRadialMenu' displays a hierarchical menu in a circular layout, and is used as a context menu typically.

Comment: Syncfusion is licensed and paid version. Is there anything we can have as an example and we can follow the source code to implement it in my project ?

Comment: What about using the `TitleView` of `ToolbarItem` to achieve this feature? The menus are added on the navigation bar, you could reach them there in the application.

Comment: Its a good suggestion but how can we float it to any point on screen.

Comment: Try to create a custom `ContentPage` and add the `TitleView` on this page. Then make the pages inherit from this custom page class, the TitleView will work on all pages.

Comment: This sounds like a good suggestion. Let me work on it and i will update here.

Comment: Hi, any updates? If you are facing some issues while implementing, try to post the particular error with the corresponding codes here.

Comment: I am finalizing another module of the app and once i will get back to this Assistive Touch challenge, will post here the update for sure. Thanks a lot for your concerns. Obliged.

Comment: Waiting for your update.